# parse.com cload code HTTP request and query

Tags: javascript, json, facebook, parse-platform

I am trying to get a list of friends from Facebook and then change the values to parse user id like this:

I got the friends list from Facebook and I try to get any item that has install item in it.

Then I try to replace the install: true with parse user id by querying the FB id to the FB I got stored in parse .com (at app install). The problem is that parse doesn't return any values no error/success msg no nothing.

```
 Parse.Cloud.define("fbtomo3", function(request, response)
 {
  var fbid =request.user.get('FaceBookId');
  var fbtoken = request.user.get('authData').facebook.access_token;
  var listFromFB ="";
  Parse.Cloud.httpRequest(
  {
   url:"https://graph.facebook.com/"+fbid+"?fields=friends.fields(installed,name)&access_token="+fbtoken+'"',
success:function(httpResponse)
{
    listFromFB = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(httpResponse.data.friends.data));
    console.log("GOT FBLIST");
    for(var item in listFromFB)
    {
        if(listFromFB[item].installed!=null)
        {
            var query = new Parse.Query("User");
                query.notEqualTo("FaceBookId",listFromFB[item].id );
                query.find({
                    success: function(results) 
                    {
                        console.log(results.id);
                        //this is where i change listFromFB[item].installed to user id but i dint get any results from query
                        //response.success(results);
                    },
                        error: function(error) {
                        //response.error("failed to look for users");
                        console.log(error.code);
                    }
                });

        }
    }
        response.success(listFromFB);
    },
    error:function(httpResponse)
    {
    console.log("didnt get it");
    response.error(httpResponse);
    }});
});
```

The query doesn't seem to work.  Can anyone help me with WHY?

I should note that the query itself works if get it in another cloudcode define function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the "Masterkey" bro. Just add this at the very top of your function :

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
```